# can't get Nusoap server working with cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, php4, nusoap

I am trying to get nusoap server working with cakephp, the problem I am assuming is that the code is within a class (controller) and nusoap is trying to execute 'function()' instead of '$this->function()'. Does anybody know of a simple workaround for this, i don't like modifying 3rd party classes...

Answer (score 1):

The best way to integrate 3rd party code into a CakePHP project is as a vendor.  I've not used Nusoap, but let's assume that the code lives in a single file called `nusoap.php`:

Drop `nusoap.php` into `/app/vendors`
Add the following code to your controller, probably in the constructor

```
App::import('vendor','nusoap');
```

I'm going to further assume that nusoap contains one or more classes that you'd need to instantiate in order to use.  Now that you've included the `nusoap.php` file, you just create an instance like you would any other class:

```
$nusoap = new Nusoap();
```

Not sure if this answers your question - if not, please post some code so we can more effectively diagnose the issue.  Good luck!

Comment: nope, i know how to use third party libs, i have a stack im using on this project. The problem is getting stubborn libs to conform to cake MVC and url routing conventions... I reckon i will need to extend the lib and rewrite/override some of the functions...